# Merge two dataframes with a single column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge two dataframes with a single column.
I have looked for the solution in other questions, but without success.

Given the dataframes

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]}
```

the desired output is

```py
x_1 | x_2
1   | 1
2   | 2
3   | 3
4   | NaN
NaN | 5
NaN | 6
```

How can I achieve this result using pandas?

If I understand correctly, I cannot exploit either the column itself or the indexes to use `pd.merge`.
I could not get the result even using `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`.

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: You can `merge`: `df1.merge(df2, left_on='x', right_on=df2['x'], how='outer')`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the desired result and it works even by inverting the dataframes. I'm sorry that the question was closed and I can't approve your answer (I had already seen the similar question, but had not found the answer). Thank you again